# JSON.parse как обработать строку

Tags: javascript, json

```
var text = JSON.parse('0{"sid":"wdUpMMfMejvC0VWEAAAc","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}')
```

```js
var array = '0{"sid":"66On4rPvwJvqXCzyAC2T","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}'.match(/(\[|{).*(\]|})/g);
var data = (array[0]);
var msg = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(msg);
```

Comment: твой код работает, просто была опечатка в сниппете во входной строке.

Comment: спасибо, я понял, не знаю как так получилось, копировал строку полностью же

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в синтаксисе JSON
Если нолик нужен, то должно быть так:
var text = JSON.parse('{"0":{"sid":"wdUpMMfMejvC0VWEAAAc","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}}')
Если без нолика, то так:
'{"sid":"wdUpMMfMejvC0VWEAAAc","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}'

Comment: ушел регулярку делать)

Comment: я исправил, это все еще не работает

Comment: @IvanSvoboda, зачем тут регулярка, если его можно просто первый символ обрезать?

Comment: Там может быть не один символ

Comment: @IvanSvoboda, может стоит решать эту проблему в месте, где эта строка собирается?

Comment: Слушаю вебсокет, получаю как параметр функции

Comment: @IvanSvoboda, то есть либо ты неправильно слушаешь, либо сервер странно собирает строку. Стоит в этих направлениях смотреть

Comment: Так: var data = (array[0]) ничего не получится, потому что json - это строка, а не массив, сначала json нужно распарсить JSON.parse

Comment: Метод string.match() возвращает массив

Comment: Как вариант - убрать ноль, т.е. всё, что находится за фигурными скобками, тогда будет так: '{"sid":"wdUpMMfMejvC0VWEAAAc","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}'

Comment: @Grundy так ошибка в коде в которую я уже вставил полученную строку

Comment: @IvanSvoboda, у тебя была опечатка во входной строке, ты забыл запятую, я поправил сниппет - сейчас все ок

Comment: @Александр ноль убирается в первой строке кода методом match(), это регулярное выражение. Т.е я полчуаю вот такой массив ["{"sid":"66On4rPvwJvqXCzyAC2T","upgrades":[]"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}"
]

Comment: Ага, теперь прокрутил до конца строки ))
Строка длинная.
Всё работает!! ))